# How can I use regular expressions in a nginx location with proxy_pass?

Tags: nginx

I would like to do something like:

```
location ~ ^/authorize/(\w+)$ {        
    proxy_pass http://my.vm/auth;
    proxy_pass_request_body on;
    proxy_set_header MY_CUSTOM_HEADER $1;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
}
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in
location given by regular expression, or inside named location,
or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in
nginx.conf
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The error message is correct, that's not a valid config. There is a workaround a vaguely remember reading about which these other questions describe

[Nginx location regex doesn't work with proxy pass](https://serverfault.com/questions/649151/nginx-location-regex-doesnt-work-with-proxy-pass)

[Nginx. Using redirects with regular expressions](https://serverfault.com/questions/577784/nginx-using-redirects-with-regular-expressions)

There are also plenty of articles to be found via Google. If the workaround above doesn't work you'll have to rethink your approach.